# Calculate time between switching on and switching off

Tags: android

I need to calculate the time between switching on and switching off the android device. And also I want to get duration the screen on for one day. Is there some way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You have to create a Receiver and listen for two intents:

> ```
> ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED - for finding out the device boot
> ACTION_SHUTDOWN - for finding out when the device is powered off
> ```

From there, you can just have a service running in the background that keeps track of the time the device started and saves the time the device was turned on for. You can either log this in a file or a database or shared preferences and retrieve it later.

For calculating how long the screen was on, you will have to have a receiver listening for these two intents:

> ```
> ACTION_SCREEN_ON 
> ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
> ```

You have to register an IntentFilter for these two intents as opposed to usually declaring them within your manifest (see this link for more details). Then you will have to simply have a flag that turns on when the screen turns on (and then a background service starts the timer or notes the time https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/) and then the flag turns off when the screen turns off (and the timer stops or the service notes the current time and then calculates the time the screen was on by subtracting the previous time with the current time).

To note the time the screen was on in 24 hours, simply maintain another 24 hour flag that resets when the time period is over.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. Do you know how to get duration the screen on for one day (the whole time the screen was turn on)?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the answer to your comment